# Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException for string input

Tags: java, class, inheritance

I am new to java.

When I try to input value for this program I get

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)
    at SugarSmashPlayer.get(Game.java:10)
    at Game.main(Game.java:44)
```

I am not sure why this happens. My guess is that I am doing something wrong with the string declaration or input method. Can you help. The program is not showing error if I declare string datatype with the input line. But I want to declare it above with the class and not inside the constructor.

> ```
> import java.util.*;
> class SugarSmashPlayer{
> Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
> int id;int n=0;String name;
> int[] arr=new int[40];
> void get(){
> id=in.nextInt();
> name=in.nextLine();
> for(int i=0;i<10;){
> arr[i]=in.nextInt();
> n++;
> if(arr[i]>=100){i++;}
> else
> {i=11;}
> }
> }
> void set(){
> System.out.println(id+" "+name+" ");
> for(int i=0;i<n;i++){System.out.println(arr[i]+" ");
> }
> }
> }
> class PremiumSugarSmashPlayer extends SugarSmashPlayer{
> void get1(){n=0;
> id=in.nextInt();
> name=in.nextLine();
> for(int i=0;i<40;){
> arr[i]=in.nextInt();
> n++;
> if(arr[i]>=100){i++;}
> else
> i=40;}
> }
> void set1(){
> System.out.println(id+" "+name+" ");
> for(int i=0;i<n;i++){System.out.println(arr[i]+" ");
> }
> }
> }
> public class Game{
> public static void main(String[] args){
> SugarSmashPlayer box=new SugarSmashPlayer();
> PremiumSugarSmashPlayer box1=new PremiumSugarSmashPlayer();
> box.get();
> box.set();
> box1.get1();
> box1.set1();
> }
> }
> ```

Comment: Please format the code and mention the line in which the exception is occuring

Comment: Hi. Thanks for replying. Sorry I am new to stackoverflow. Not sure how to format the code. The error occurs if I give abc which is a string input for the name variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input was:

```
1
abc
```

`nextInt` reads the next token of an input as an int and hence would read the integer value of 1 into `id` field.
Then if you use `nextLine` then it would initialize the `name` field with `""`. Javadoc of `nextLine` states:

> Advances this scanner past the current line and returns the input that was skipped.This method returns the rest of the current line, excluding any lineseparator at the end. The position is set to the beginning of the nextline.

Then `arr[i] = in.nextInt()` would be trying to read `abc`, and hence error is caused.

You should either input as:

```
1 abc
532
235
```

or you need to change the code as:

```java
id = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine()); //whole line is read
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using

```
id = in.nextInt();
```

This exception will happen if someone enters something else than a number.

You should better call `nextLine()` and then check if the input is a number.

Comment: Thanks for replying. But my input was 1,abc and goes on. As per the code I have given an integer id and a string name. But as soon as I enter abc it shows the error